How can I define a struct which has a member with unknown size?
I defined a struct following table 17 in PLDM Base spec MultipartReceive response. This struct is used for receiving data from the other component. Following the spec, we can't know the sizing of data and below it have another uint32_t crc checksum. So how can I define this response struct?
MultipartReceive response
I decided to define it like below and CRC checksum will be a part of data[].
typedef struct {
    uint8_t completion_code;        // completion code
    uint8_t transfer_flag;
    uint32_t next_transfer_handle;
    uint32_t data_length_bytes;
    uint8_t data[];
} __attribute__((packed)) MultipartReceiveResp_T;

But my teammate said I should define this struct like below for safety:
typedef struct {
    uint8_t completion_code;        // completion code
    uint8_t transfer_flag;
    uint32_t next_transfer_handle;
    uint32_t data_length_bytes;
    uint8_t data[1];
} __attribute__((packed)) MultipartReceiveResp_T;

Which option is better? and Why? I am confused about why we must define a single array for this.

Flexarr is a C99 feature. Additionally, most compilers provide a similar extension with an explicit size 0 even in C89 mode.

Your teammate doesn't know what they are talking about... The terms you are looking for here is flexible array member (good) versus "the struct hack" (bad).

@o11c Most compilers did not, only gcc. Zero size arrays are dangerous because if you happen to have a plain array elsewhere in your code int arr[N] and for whatever the reason end up with a N == 0, that severe bug will silently pass gcc/gnu compilation. Best practice is to never use GNU C extensions anywhere.

@Lundin I'm pretty sure I checked and MSVC does the exact same thing (and this is useful as a much saner alternative to C++'s EBO). The only real problem I've ever seen mentioned is that / sizeof() would crash, but I've never seen that attempted in practice for the kinds of code where zero-size arrays are used.

@o11c The Windows API contained lots of struct hack stuff such as bitmap headers etc so they probably had some some similar mechanic in MSVC. Another problem with the struct hack apart from out of bounds access, is that there might be trailing padding bytes at the end of the struct. Depending on if the struct sat well with the fundamental alignment or not, we may or may not be writing data into padding bytes. Which will "work", but it won't be reliable at all. As usual, you can't argue against undefined behavior by demonstrating how one particular compiler behaves.


Which option is better? and Why?

uint8_t data[]; is better because it correctly does not specify a size for an array that does not have a fixed size. uint8_t data[1]; is worse because it falsely tells the compiler the array has one element when that is generally not the case.
For an array member whose size would be determined at run time, defining the array to have one element or zero elements was a kludge used in old versions of C. The C standard has since changed to provide a way to define flexible array members, using the [] syntax. This new method should be favored over the kludge.
Among other effects, if you define the array to have one element and then access it with, say MyStructure.data[i], it is conforming behavior for the compiler to deduce that i must have the value zero, since that is the only value defined for accessing an array defined to have one element. So, if you had a loop such as:
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    …
    t[i] = MyStructure.data[i];
}

the compiler could optimize it to:
if (n)
{
    …
    t[0] = MyStructure.data[0];
}

thus eliminating all the iterations of the loop where i would be 1, 2, 3, or more. Generally, when you lie to the compiler, bad things may happen.
As for what you should do, this looks like data that is read into a buffer from some communication device. Methods for correctly interpreting the buffer as a MultipartReceiveResp_T structure depend on circumstances. If the buffer was dynamically allocated, then copying bytes into it, as by a network-read routine, may satisfy the C standard’s requirements for effectively creating a structure object in the buffer, and you could safely alias the buffer with the structure type. However, if the buffer was defined as a static array of char, such aliasing would not be safe absent a guarantee from the compiler. For further guidance, you would have to show more of the code involved.
As for accessing the checksum after the data in data, you will need to calculate the address, and then again a correct method for accessing it may depend on circumstances. Since data is an array of character type (barring a bizarre definition of uint8_t in your C implementation), you can easily calculate N bytes beyond the start of the data member and then use memcpy to copy sizeof (uint32) bits into a variable defined to have the uint32 type.

thank u for ur response
